# Using Android's `Timer.schedule` in Python

Tags: python, android, timer, android-scripting

Could someone explain how to use the [Timer.schedule](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20java.util.Date%29) - that is used for scheduling tasks - in [Python](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/wiki/PythonAndroidAPI)?

Note that Python's `time.sleep` will not work in Android.

Answer (score 0):

time.sleep does work on the Android Scripting Environment (at least for the last 5 releases or so). I've just tested it on the interpreter console.

On the other hand, some dialogs (like makeToast, for instance) won't hold the script execution while they're being displayed. Perhaps that's why you may be feeling time.sleep doesn't work.